# URL dispatching in web.py

Tags: python, html, django, url, web.py

In Django whenever I have to use site navigation I use the [Reverse resolution of URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls). This way I can make django -render- each new html page and pass that page whatever arguments I want to through the views.

However I am wondering how should I do this in web.py. For instance, I have a web.py template that contains a variable `$user`. At some point in the main webpage a simple button contains a link of the form

```
<a href="account.html">Account</a>
```

which redirects a user to his account page. Now, I need to pass `$user` on to `account.html` so that he/she can change his/her details. The problem is that since I can't directly link to `account.html` cause it's not a static page, how should I go through web.py and use its `render` method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the best way to do this would be with a [session variable](http://webpy.org/sessions/). That kind of variable can be consistent across several pages.